# What is the domain of a function in this definition?

Tags: functions, terminology

Let $f:X\to Y$ is a function from $X$ to $Y$.

1. Is the statement {($f:X\to Y$ is a function from $X$ to $Y$) $\to$ $f \subseteq X \times Y$} correct?
2. From textbook "Mathematical Analysis", the author Garling said:

   > The set $\left \{ a\in X :\textrm{there exists } b\in Y \textrm{ such that } (a,b)\in f \right \}$ is then called the ***domain*** of $f$, and the set $\left \{ b\in Y :\textrm{there exists } a\in X \textrm{ such that } (a,b)\in f \right \}$ is called the ***codomain*** of $f$.

   But in [Wikipedia's Domain of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) it says:

   > Given a function $f:X\to Y$, the set $X$ is the ***domain*** of $f$ and the set $Y$ is the ***codomain*** of $f$.

From my understanding, the set $\left \{ a\in X :\textrm{there exists } b\in Y \,\,\text{such that}\,\, (a,b)\in f \right \}$ actually DIFFERS from set $X$.

Please explain why we have such different definitions of ***domain*** of a function!

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you think that they are different?

Comment: Let X = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, Y = {5, 6, 7, 8, 9} and f = {(0, 5), (1, 6)}. As a result, $\left \{ a\in X :\textrm{there exists } b\in Y \textrm{ such that } (a,b)\in f \right \}$ = {0, 1} <> X.

Comment: In that case either $f$ is not defined on the whole of $X$, or $f$ is restricted to $\{0,1\}$. You have to give the function in order to know the domain, and you haven't done that. You have just exhibited some subset of $X\times Y$.

Comment: In my textbook, function is defined as a RELATION (as a result, subset) on Cartesian product. And I gave you that subset!

Comment: But the function arising from that relation is not defined on the whole of $X$, so of course its domain is not equal to $X$.

Comment: Yes, if $f$ is a function and it is a subset of $X\times Y$ then its domain can be found as the set described in your question, and this set can differ from $X$. But that is not a decent way to **define** its domain. In Wikipedia a decent definition is given and in that context the described set equals the domain of the function.

Comment: Also, why do you use the symbol <> to (supposedly) denote an inequality?

Comment: I use $<>$ to express $differs from$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for wikipedia here.

According to that definition a function $f$ is a subset of $X\times Y$ having the special property that for every $a\in X$ there is a unique $b\in Y$ with $\langle a,b\rangle\in f$.

Then:
$$\{a\in X\mid\text{ there exists }b\in Y\text{ such that }\langle a,b\rangle\in f\}=X$$so there is no ambiguity with the definition in your textbook where it concerns the **domain**.

Usually the set: $$\{b\in Y\mid\text{ there exists }a\in X\text{ such that }\langle a,b\rangle\in f\}$$ is **not** labelled as the codomain of function $f$ but as the **range** or the **image** of function $f$. It is actually a subset of the **codomain** $Y$.

Actually domain and range can be defined for *every* set $A$ by: $$\mathsf{dom}A:=\{a\mid\exists b[\langle a,b\rangle\in A]\}$$ and:$$\mathsf{ran}A:=\{b\mid\exists a[\langle a,b\rangle\in A]\}$$

In set theory a function is defined as a set of ordered pairs such that for every $a\in\mathsf{dom}f$ there is not more than one $b$ with $\langle a,b\rangle\in f$.

For this function $f$ any set that includes $\mathsf{ran}f$ as a subset can serve as codomain of the function.

A question that rises is then: if $Y$ and $Z$ can both serve as codomain of $f$ and $Y\neq Z$ then are the functions $f:X\to Y$ and $f:X\to Z$ different or not? In set-theory this question is answered by: "no". But e.g. in the theory of categories it is answered by: "yes".

Comment: Let X = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, Y = {5, 6, 7, 8, 9} and f = {(0, 5), (1, 6)}. As a result, $\{a\in X\mid\text{ there exists }b\in Y\text{ such that }\langle a,b\rangle\in f\}$ = {0, 1} <> X.

Comment: I have gave you an example in which two definitions give different sets of domain.

Comment: @leanhdung. But that $f$ does *not* have all of $X$ as its domain. It doesn't satisfy that "for every $a\in X$ there is a unique $b\in Y$ with $\langle a,b\rangle\in f$."

Comment: I thinks in general term, $f$ does not need to have all of $X$ in its domain.

Comment: Then it is *not* a *function* on $X$. It will just be a *relation* between $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: The things together that come from your textbook do not provide in a full definition of **function**. Actually they start with an $f$ which is a function allready and is apparantly a subset of $X\times Y$. Based on that data the domain of that function is found as a subset of $X$. This on a correct way. Also the codomain is found, but this in a way that does not go along with the definition on wikipedia.

Comment: @md2perpe In the above post, i forgot to mention the property of this relation:  each input is related to exactly one output! To be precise: we define a function, or, synonymously, a mapping, or a map, from a set $A$ to a set $B$ to be a relation $f$ on $A×B$ which satisfies the
condition:
for each $a ∈ A$, there is a unique $b ∈ B$ such that $(a, b) ∈ f$.

Comment: @drhab, in my textbook, the author Garling define $a function$, or, synonymously, a mapping, or a map, from a set $A$ to a set $B$ to be a relation $f$ on $A×B$ which satisfies the condition: for each $a ∈ A$, there is a unique $b ∈ B$ such that $(a, b) ∈ f$.

Comment: Yes, in that context $A$ **is its domain**. If $f$ is indeed a function from $A$ to $B$ then - if moreover we have $f\subseteq X\times Y$ - the set $\{a\in X\mid\exists b\in Y[(a,b)\in f]\}$ coincides with $A$. It might differ from $X$, but that is no problem. $X$ was not defined to be its domain. We only had $f\subseteq X\times Y$.

Comment: @drhab I got it, sincere thanks for you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the text you've quoted, however in all places that I've come across when writing $f:X \to Y$ we mean that $f$ is defined on all of $X$. In which case:

Let $f: X \to Y$ be given.

Let $x \in X$. Set $y = f(x)$. Then $x \in \{a \in X : \exists b \in Y (a,b) \in f\}$.

If $x \in \{a \in X : \exists b \in Y (a,b) \in f\}$ then $x \in X$. The sets are equal. If $f$ isn't defined on all of $X$ I'd assume they would note it somewhere.

Saying $f \subset X \times Y$ is a bit  weird. I'm familiar with saying the graph of $f$ is in $X \times Y$; $\Gamma(f) \subset X \times Y$.

Comment: In my textbook, function is defined as a RELATION (as a result, subset) on Cartesian product.

Comment: @leanhdung. A relation is a subset of the Cartesian product. A function is a special kind of relation.